# Web components loading unknown component

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am creating an application where I want to load the different components from a string (which will be represented in my database).

So I've written a test (before getting the data) where I test the option for loading these dynamically and without me knowing exactly which component to load at a given time:

So far I've succeeded with the dynamic import:

```
  import(`${this.sdkbtnString}`);
```

Now I've tried a few methods to place a tag that I don't really know what is ahead of time. For instance I attempted:

```
<${this.sdkiconbtnString}></${this.sdkiconbtnString}>
```

This naive approach did not work.

Then I attempted to see if I could get something from using:

```
const t = async import(`${this.sdkbtnString}`);
```

However I can't really use this for anything as it just returns a module definition.

So how can I load a tag where I don't know exactly what the tag should be. Also what do you feel about this approach is there a better way?

Comment: Without much thought: **keep** it in a String, then parse it with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser **once** you expect the Custom Elements to exist. If this is about SVG icons, take a peek at my pet-project ``<svg-icon>`` (5000+ icons, work in progress) https://iconmeister.github.io

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman hey mate thank you for your answer. this apporach could work but what can i do about event's or two way binding of data?

Comment: With native you have to develop all yourself. Lit-Element+Lit-HTML will help with the 2-way binding. Events you still have to implement yourself. Doing everything with Events (via a shared parentNode) is the most flexible approach. But I am not sure if Lit can handle your unknown elements scenario at all... I prefer to do everything with native.

Comment: Maybe not related. This JSFiddle (to me) is the basics of Components and Events: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/au25to79/  (Run in Firefox, Chrome sometimes complains about ``console.group``)